# Two functions that map from $R^5$ to $R^2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of two linear maps $T_1$ and $T_2$ that have the same null spaces, but such that $T_1$ is not a scalar multiple of $T_2$.

I was looking through examples in my book and I seem to have gotten stuck on this one. Any help? Hints are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0&  0&  0\end{pmatrix}$ be a solution?

Comment: pick any linear map from $\mathbb{R}^5$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $T_1$. Compose it with any non-trivial rotation of $\mathbb{R}^2$ to get your $T_2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$T_1(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (x_1,x_2),$$ and $$T_2(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (x_2,x_1),$$
then $$\ker(T_1) = \ker(T_2) = \{ (0,0,x_3,x_4,x_5): x_3,x_4,x_5 \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
and for every $t$ we have
$$T_1(1,2,0,0,0)= (1,2) \neq t (2,1) = T_2(1,2,0,0,0),$$
i.e. $T_1$ is a not a scalar multiple of $T_2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let (as matrices over the canonical bases):
$$ T_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
and 
$$ T_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix} $$
both have null space ${\rm span}\{e_3, e_4, e_5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Take the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^{2},\mathbb{R}^{5}$
and construct two linear maps is such a way - first map the same $3$
vectors in the basis for $\mathbb{R}^{5}$ to $0$.

Now we are left to define what the other $2$ vectors map into - how
many ways can you map them into the basis we have for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$
in a way that satisfies the requirement for the map ?